# How to configure defaults for a parameter with multiple values for a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, parameters, maven-plugin, defaults

I'm writing a Maven plugin and I am using default values for all parameters such as this:

```
/**
 * The file with the site structure.
 * 
 * @parameter expression="${generateSite.siteFile}" default-value="${basedir}/src/oda/site.xml"
 */
private File siteFile;
```

Now I am adding a new parameter which is a collection. Is there a way to set default values for a parameter like the following one?

```
/**
 * A list of file/directory names to exclude in the processing.
 * 
 * @parameter ????
 */
private Set<String> excludes;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To **my** knowledge, this is actually not possible, there is no real way to specify default values for *Parameter Types With Multiple Values* (like Arrays, Collections,  or Maps), at least not as `parameter`. I had to do this in the past too and, having read threads like [array (or collecton) as a default-value of a mojo configuration parameter](http://markmail.org/message/maws2hydvznbethy) or [configuring a list as default value for a plugin parameter](http://markmail.org/message/uc552knw3hyy4lyo), I ended up setting defaults in the `execute()` method, like Chris mentioned in a comment to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659087/how-to-configure-defaults-for-a-parameter-with-multiple-values-for-a-maven-plugin/1659355#1659355) (see for example the [flexmojos:wrapper](http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/wrapper-mojo.html) plugin [sources](http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/xref/org/sonatype/flexmojos/htmlwrapper/HtmlWrapperMojo.html#718) and the [parameters](http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/wrapper-mojo.html#parameters) parameter).

Comment: That's the answer I suspected I would get. I had a brief glimpse at the Maven source code, but then it seemed I needed the Plexus source, too -- which is where I stopped. Let's just assume you are right ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm still not 100% sure but flexmojos being developed by Sonatype, I guess they are representative of state of the art and are a trustful reference.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that Set is explicitly supported but the following will work:

```
/**
 * A list of file/directory names to exclude in the processing.
 *
 * @parameter
 */
private String[] myFiles;
```

You can then configure it using:

```
<myFiles>
  <param>value1</param>
  <param>value2</param>
</myFiles>
```

BTW this was taken from the **Parameter Types With Multiple Values** section on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) which also details other ways to allow parameters with multiple values.

Comment: According to the documentation you link to yourself any java.util.Collection should work -- this is how I came up with the original plan. It definitely does work with a Set in the way you describe it. But that is not setting default values, it is the normal project-specific configuration. The documentation does not mention anything about setting default values on the multi-valued parameters (or not being able to).

Comment: Sorry, I obviously didn't read the question properly!

However, I believe the answer is no. A few years ago I was seeking a similar answer on the Maven mailing lists, and I only found "I don't think so" answers. Digging around the Plexus code (which Maven uses a container) and this supported that answer.

In the places that we wanted to do this, we ended up just setting the defaults in the execute() method.